# What is the Correct place to initialize class variables in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

A: initialize class variable in init block

```
private class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    val menuImg: ImageView
    val txtMenu: TextView

    init {
        menuImg = view.find(R.id.menuImg)
        txtMenu = view.find(R.id.txtMenu)
    }
}
```

B: initialize class variable direct in class block

```
 private class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    val menuImg: ImageView = view.find(R.id.menuImg)
    val txtMenu: TextView =  view.find(R.id.txtMenu)
}
```

what different between two code and why ?.

Comment: there is no different between them. `init` block is a convenient way that initializing a property need  more than  one statement. and your code didn't having any casting expression that can't be compiled.

Comment: Watch out for the duplicate `= menuImg` in the second code snippet, otherwise I prefer that version; declare and assign in one place. (edit: wow you fixed that fast!!)

Comment: holi-java  thank  you for explanation;

Comment: Not at all. glad it helped you, :)

Comment: – CodeConfident , I note that after reread my question :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference in the execution of those options A and B: 
Property initializers (immediately assigning a value) and Initializer blocks (using init block). But for simple initializations like your code, it is common to use the Property initializer -- option B in your case.

But be aware of the execution order of the initializers if you use both versions in your code.

Quoting from [this article](https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546):

> First, default constructor arguments are evaluated, starting with
>   argument to the constructor you call directly, followed by arguments
>   to any delegated constructors. Next, **initializers (property
>   initializers and init blocks) are executed in the order that they are
>   defined in the class, top-to-bottom**. Finally, constructors are
>   executed, starting with the primary constructor and moving outward
>   through delegated constructors until the constructor that you called
>   is executed.

Comment: That was very helpful