# How to use a calculation in multiple property initializations in Kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin, constructor, initialization

I want to do a potentially costly calculation once, to use its result to initialise two class properties that ideally should be `val`s. Is there a correct way of doing this?

eg:

```kotlin
class Foo(aIn: Double, bIn: Double) {
    val a = aIn * bigCalc(aIn, bIn)
    val b = bIn * bigCalc(aIn, bIn)
}
```

I cannot do it in an init block because the result cannot be accessed outside that, I would prefer not to make a and b `var`s as they should be immutable, and I would rather not leave it as in the example as this would be slow for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `init`

```
class Foo(aIn: Double, bIn: Double) {
    val a: Double
    val b: Double
    
    init {
        a = aIn * bigCalc(aIn, bIn)
        b = bIn * bigCalc(aIn, bIn)
    }
}
```

However this is same as the code you have. Both initialize the variables when the class is created. So using `init` doesn't improve performance. Check this [similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674385/603742).

Comment: This is great, i can call ```bigCalc``` just once in the ```init```, which is all I was hoping for. Many thanks.