# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Sorry for the long title, however, I am unsure where this error is at in my code, however, I do suspect the error lies in the implementation of the `liveData` and `Observation`.

The app which I am working on is an Unscrambler word app where users have to unscramble the letters displayed on the fragment. My code so far consists of 2 Kotlin classes listed below, a `fragment` and a `ViewModel` class.

I have currently assigned the variable `_currentScrambledWord` as a `MutableLiveData<String>()` and utilised the backing property in `ViewModel.kt`

```
private val _currentScrambledWord = MutableLiveData<String>()
val currentScrambledWord: LiveData<String>
    get() = _currentScrambledWord
```

I then tried to attach an observer to the `GameFragment` using the code below.

```
viewModel.currentScrambledWord.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        { newWord -> binding.textViewUnscrambledWord.text = newWord
        })
```

From what I understand the `LiveData` simplifies the process of retrieving data from the `ViewModel` reducing the amount of code needed.

Here is the error I found in Logcat

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

The error lines in the logcat is as follows

```
at com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameViewModel.getNextWord(GameViewModel.kt:57)
at com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameViewModel.<init>(GameViewModel.kt:18)
at com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment.getViewModel(GameFragment.kt:39)
at com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment.onViewCreated(GameFragment.kt:76)
```

**Viewmodel.kt**

```
class GameViewModel:ViewModel() {

private var wordsList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
private lateinit var currentWord: String

init {
    Log.d("GameFragment", "GameViewModel created!")
    getNextWord()
}

private var _score = 0
val score: Int
    get() = _score

private var _currentWordCount = 0
val currentWordCount: Int
    get() = _currentWordCount

private var _currentScrambledWord = MutableLiveData<String>()
val currentScrambledWord: LiveData<String>
    get() = _currentScrambledWord

private fun increaseScore() {
    _score += SCORE_INCREASE
}

fun isUserWordCorrect(playerWord: String): Boolean {
    if (playerWord.equals(currentWord, true)) {
        increaseScore()
        return true
    }
    return false
}


private fun getNextWord() {
    currentWord = allWordsList.random()
    val tempWord = currentWord.toCharArray()
    tempWord.shuffle()

    while (String(tempWord).equals(currentWord, false)) {
        tempWord.shuffle()
    }
    if (wordsList.contains(currentWord)) {
        getNextWord()
    } else {
        _currentScrambledWord.value = String(tempWord)
        ++_currentWordCount
        wordsList.add(currentWord)
    }
}
fun nextWord(): Boolean {
    return if (currentWordCount < MAX_NO_OF_WORDS) {
        getNextWord()
        true
    } else false
}



override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    Log.d("GameFragment", "GameViewModel destroyed!")
}

fun reinitializeData() {
    _score = 0
    _currentWordCount = 0
    wordsList.clear()
    getNextWord()
}





}
```

**GameFragment.kt**

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {




private val viewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels()


// Binding object instance with access to the views in the game_fragment.xml layout
private lateinit var binding: GameFragmentBinding

// Create a ViewModel the first time the fragment is created.
// If the fragment is re-created, it receives the same GameViewModel instance created by the
// first fragment



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = GameFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    Log.d("GameFragment1", "GameFragment created/re-created!")



    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    Log.d("OnViewCreated", "OnViewCreated working")
    // Setup a click listener for the Submit and Skip buttons.
    binding.submit.setOnClickListener { onSubmitWord() }
    binding.skip.setOnClickListener { onSkipWord() }
    // Update the UI

    binding.score.text = getString(R.string.score, 0)
    binding.wordCount.text = getString(
            R.string.word_count, 0, MAX_NO_OF_WORDS)

    viewModel.currentScrambledWord.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        { newWord -> binding.textViewUnscrambledWord.text = newWord
        })
}

/*
* Checks the user's word, and updates the score accordingly.
* Displays the next scrambled word.
*/


private fun onSubmitWord() {
    val playerWord = binding.textInputEditText.text.toString()

    if (viewModel.isUserWordCorrect(playerWord)) {
        setErrorTextField(false)
        if (!viewModel.nextWord()) {
            showFinalScoreDialog()
        }
    } else {
        setErrorTextField(true)
    }
}



/*
 * Skips the current word without changing the score.
 * Increases the word count.
 */
private fun onSkipWord() {
    if (viewModel.nextWord()) {
        setErrorTextField(false)

    } else {
        showFinalScoreDialog()
    }
}

/*
 * Gets a random word for the list of words and shuffles the letters in it.
 */
private fun getNextScrambledWord(): String {
    val tempWord = allWordsList.random().toCharArray()
    tempWord.shuffle()
    return String(tempWord)
}

/*
 * Re-initializes the data in the ViewModel and updates the views with the new data, to
 * restart the game.
 */

private fun showFinalScoreDialog() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.congratulations))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.you_scored, viewModel.score))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.exit)) { _, _ ->
            exitGame()
        }
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.play_again)) { _, _ ->
            restartGame()
        }
        .show()

}

private fun restartGame() {
    viewModel.reinitializeData()
    setErrorTextField(false)

}

/*
 * Exits the game.
 */
private fun exitGame() {
    activity?.finish()
}

/*
* Sets and resets the text field error status.
*/
private fun setErrorTextField(error: Boolean) {
    if (error) {
        binding.textField.isErrorEnabled = true
        binding.textField.error = getString(R.string.try_again)
    } else {
        binding.textField.isErrorEnabled = false
        binding.textInputEditText.text = null
    }
}

/*
 * Displays the next scrambled word on screen.
 */



override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    Log.d("GameFragment", "GameFragment destroyed!")
}
}
```

Comment: The logcat will also tell you exactly what line the error happens on. Which line is it (look in the stack trace for the last line that is from your package and indicate it in the question)?

Comment: I have just updated the question with the error lines

Comment: Variable viewModel.currentScrambleWord is nullable.  Give it a default value during initialisation, or inside your LiveData observer, check that it is not null before proceeding to use its value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialization in Kotlin happens in the order written (top to bottom). Because your `init` block is listed *before* you initialize `_currentScrambledWord`, it is null when you try to use it in `init`. You should move the `init` block to the end of the class definition, so it is at least after the LiveData, something like this:

```kotlin
private var wordsList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
private var currentWord: String = "" // doesn't have to be lateinit if you always set it in "init" - better yet, just put a default

private var _score = 0
val score: Int
    get() = _score

private var _currentWordCount = 0
val currentWordCount: Int
    get() = _currentWordCount

private var _currentScrambledWord = MutableLiveData<String>()
val currentScrambledWord: LiveData<String>
    get() = _currentScrambledWord

// other stuff

// init at the very bottom
init {
    Log.d("GameFragment", "GameViewModel created!")
    getNextWord()
}
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673830/what-is-the-correct-place-to-initialize-class-variables-in-kotlin) for some additional context.